# What can I do to help me sustain frequent long-ish rides?

Tags: commuter, technique, nutrition, heart-rate

After nearly a year of commuting by bicycle to and from work 2-3 days per week, I have recently started cycling to work every day, 5 days a week, rain or shine.  My commute is about 11-15 miles each way (depending which route I take), including some steep hills (followed by stop signs, so I don't even get the benefit of coasting down-hill). I obtained a new road bike of decent quality along with reasonable quality clipless shoes, gloves, shorts, a jersey, and a heart rate monitor.  I am not very physically fit (5'9" 200 lbs), but improving.  Now 2 weeks into daily commuting plus occasional weekend riding, I am feeling very sore and fatigued and can barely sustain 80% of the effort I was achieving at the start.

What should I eat (and when should I eat it) to help me sustain this effort, yet also help me lose weight and improve my physical fitness?  Is it important to ride at a relatively low effort level, keeping my heart rate in the base zone, or should I occasionally push it into aerobic endurance or even anaerobic zones?  What heart rate(s) should I aim for? What cadence should I try to maintain?

Any advice from experienced commuters in a similar position would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will take your body more than the two weeks to start adjusting (this is a GOOD thing, you're getting in better shape). There are folks that will swear by various nutrition guidelines to assist, but IMO, just eat healthy and keep at it. Your body will get used to the abuse in a couple more weeks. If you feel especially sore/fatigued, take a rest day mid week. Soon you won't need one. Happy Riding.

Comment: @KenHiatt is right. Food isn't your problem. It's the sudden increase in your overall weeklong exercise load. Most experts recommend an increase of 10-15% per week with no increase about every fourth week. You've basically doubled your weeklong load. It's not that it can't be done, it just leaves you feeling fatigued and discouraged and causes a lot of people to give up. Just keep slogging through and you'll be good in a couple/few weeks.

Comment: @jimirings Do you have a source for increasing only 10-15% per week with no increase every fourth week?  That seems like an interesting guideline.  Truth is I also had some previous weeks with 4 rides, but also some with 1 or even none if it was snowing, so 2-3 is sort of an average, not a range.

Comment: @TalFishman If you Google "10 percent rule" you'll find loads. A lot of it will be about running just because more people try running at some point in their lives than cycling, but it's more or less the same for any sport. It's also usually interpreted as 10% more time or distance, but it can also be the same time and distance with 10% more effort. This is hard to gauge though unless you have a device to measure the watts that you're putting out.

Comment: @TalFishman I didn't mean that to be a dismissive "Google it yourself." It's just that there's some disagreement on how strictly it should be applied, whether the rest week should be less than the previous week or the same, etc.

Comment: @jimirings Thanks, but I wonder how much of that advice is related to injury prevention, which is a much bigger risk in high-impact running than low-impact cycling.  Also, back to the question itself, I know I'm making a big jump, the question is what to do to make the jump easier.

Comment: 15 miles is no great distance.  You do need to eat something, with a few carbs, before you start (and give it a few minutes to digest), but nothing special.  Be sure to drink enough fluid, though, before and during the ride.  Cut back on your riding a bit, until you recover.  (There is a vague possibility that you have a metabolic disorder such as myoadenylate deaminase deficiency, but I wouldn't worry about it until you've been several months without improvement.)

Comment: @TalFishman The 10% rule is more or less uniform to any endurance sport. Injury is part of it to be sure, but it's also about accumulated fatigue. Your body wants to rest while it rebuilds muscle. If you never give it the chance, you just get more and more tired with every passing day/week. It will *eventually* even out though. It just takes time.

Comment: Just because you have to make stops doesn't mean you don't get the benefit of coasting downhill! The one "waste" is when you're already off the hill and on the flat, and you cannot keep the kinetic energy because there is a stop.  Well, that kinetic energy isn't something you can keep for long anyway. Within a few hundred yards, most of it is dissipated in air drag.

Comment: @Kaz Taking those stop sign out would definitely reduce my time by a couple of minutes.  I'm probably going about 35 MPH at the point that I have to stop, while on flats I can rarely sustain over 20 MPH.  Thankfully, the Parks Dept is working on a new ramp that would remove the stop, but it won't be ready for another year.

Comment: @TalFishman Oh, taking stops, or generally, using your brakes and going slowly down the hill, will add to your *time*, for sure, but not significantly to the overall effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep at it. The human body is very adaptable and you'll soon get fitter.

Don't worry too much about food and nutrition at the moment, that only matters when you're cycling at a competitive level, you just need to make sure you've had breakfast before you ride in the morning. Regardless of cycling/weight loss you should try and eat a healthy balanced diet anyway.

Don't worry about heart rate and zones. At the moment you just need to get to the level where you can comfortably manage 5 days riding. This will come naturally. Its hard at the start (as you are experiencing) but it will get easier every week.

In a month or two you will be able to manage the ride no problems and only then should you think about pushing your performance. That's when the heart monitor is useful.

Comment: The best answer I think. To make a minor additional comment regarding pace - I too ride to and from work and on the way to work I ride as slowly as needed to avoid sweating, then on the way home I ride as hard as I can to maximize the workout. The thinking here is I'd rather not be tired and stinky at work, whereas when I get home I can take a shower and rest immediately.

Comment: Luckily there are changing and showers at my workplace.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need more rest. It's easy to forget that you don't get fitter and stronger during exercise, but when your body recovers *after* exercise. I admire your motivation and the effort you're putting in, if you don't get enough rest in between exercise, it may actually take longer to get fit (and be more painful).

By rest I mean whatever ordinary daily activity that you're already accustomed to. Maybe a short walk to shops, daily chores whatever is normal for you. If you're especially worn out, then a bit of extra sleep can work wonders in my experience.

It will depend on the rest of your lifestyle, but aim to take at least one, but ideally 3, days off between cycling. YMMV, but I find this is how long it takes for the aches to subside after some unusual exercise.

If you absolutely must get fit super-fast, then at least switch to another form of exercise on "rest" days. Swimming for example should give your legs a rest.

Comment: Definitely agree. Having a GOOD sleep between rides is a must.

Answer (score 3):

My commute is also ~15 miles. Certainly don't worry about that heart monitor (not for commuting at least). Try not to eat any processed flours (including bread!). My breakfast is whole oats soaked in milk with nuts, berries, and whatever else you fancy.

For the ride home it's important to get that same carb boost before you ride home (I eat 300-400 calories worth about 20-30 minutes before I ride). I don't eat during these rides (no need, if you fuel up beforehand).

To lose weight you'll need to control what you eat during the day at work and after work once you get home. That's where I personally eat the most. It's easy to down plenty of unchecked calories. You're suppose to be hungry sometimes. Don't eat at the first pang of hunger.

Comment: The heart rate monitor helps me gauge how much effort I'm putting in, so I don't overdo it early in the week.